# I want to increase my number by one, 7 times from 0 in label of JFrame at specific location

Tags: java, for-loop, paint

Here's my code:

```
  for (int count = 0; count < 7; count++) {
    int z=0;
    z++;
    label = new JLabel(Integer.toString(z));
    label.setLocation(12, 32);
    add(label,Color.white);
 }
```

I have two problems. One is with location. It is at upward center while I want (12,32). Other is with increment of z; it's not increasing and remains fixed at one. [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwGo3.png).
Alternatively, tell me an easy way to perform this task. I want labels in bullseye from 1-10 in each oval.
This is the full code if you not understand:

```
    package bullseye;
import javax.swing.JPanel; import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
public class BullsEye extends JPanel {  
    private JLabel label;

   public BullsEye()   {      
   setBackground(Color.white);
   setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,600));

      for (int count = 0; count < 7; count++)      {
      int z=0;
      z++;
      label = new JLabel(Integer.toString(z));
      label.setLocation(12, 32);
                add(label,Color.white);

            }
   }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics page)   {
      super.paintComponent(page);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) page;
      g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));  
//Graphics 2D is used to increase stroke of white ovals.
//As we place white ovals as draw (not fill),  and not use draw command for black ovals.
//So, stroke of white ovals only increase to 3 from 1 (default value).
      int x = 150, y = 150, diameter = 300;


      for (int count = 0; count < 7; count++)      {

          page.setColor(Color.white);
          page.drawOval(x, y, diameter, diameter);
          page.setColor(Color.black);
          page.fillOval(x, y, diameter, diameter);
          diameter = diameter-50;
          x = x+25;
          y = y+25;
      }
      page.setColor(Color.white);
      page.fillOval(300-(10/2), 300-(10/2) , 10 , 10);
      //Centre of frame is 300, 300. But oval starts its first point from 300, 300.
      //As dimensions of oval are 10, 10. So, it means they have diametre of 10, 10 and radius of 5.
      //So, from this we know centre is at 300-5, 300-5.
      x = 250/2; y = 250/2; diameter = 350;
      for (int count = 0; count < 3; count++){
          page.setColor(Color.black);
          page.drawOval(x, y, diameter, diameter);
          diameter = diameter+50;
          x = x-25;
          y=y-25;

      }
   }
      public static void main(String[] args)   {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Bullseye");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      BullsEye panel = new BullsEye();
      frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);   } 
}
```

Comment: Please, indent your code.

Comment: Have you tried to step through that code with a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)?

Answer (score 0):

You never use  `count` in the `for` loop
and `z` is badly used and also useless as `count` has already the value you need.

```
  for (int count = 0; count < 7; count++) {
    label = new JLabel(Integer.toString(count));
    label.setLocation(12, 32);
    add(label,Color.white);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. But what about location. Labels are not at dimensions I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare z outside of the loop

```
int z=0;
for (int count = 0; count < 7; count++)      {
    z++;
    label = new JLabel(Integer.toString(z));
    label.setLocation(12, 32);
    add(label,Color.white);
 }
```

And please indent your code for readability.

Comment: Thanks. But what about location. Labels are not at dimensions I mentioned.

Comment: try adding this to the main panel.setLayout(null);

Comment: or setLayout(null) in the BullsEye()